# getting the text of checkboxes in jquery (not values)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Dynamic `checkboxes` are created using the below code.

```
    var list = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
         $('#cContainer').append('<input type="checkbox" name="catChkBox" class="ckbox"
          id = "'+ data[i].id +'" value="'+ data[i].id + '" /> ' + data[i].name + '<br 
          />');
    }
```

The above code is inside `document.ready` function. I want to collect the checked values ie. `data[i].name` outside `document.ready` and put it in a list.

I tried the below code which displays only the `id`. But what I need is the text. Here it is `data[i].name` (I get this from dwr call)

```
function showSelectedValues()
{
  alert("--------------" + $("input[name=catChkBox]:checked").map(
     function () {return this.value;}).get().join(","));
}
```

I will call `showSelectedValues()` from some other method where I will make use of the values. 
Any idea for this???

Comment: hey , why you aren't marking none of answers to your questions as accepted !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each `checkbox` add a `label`

```
var list = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
     $('#cContainer').append('<input type="checkbox" name="catChkBox" class="ckbox"
      id = "'+ data[i].id +'" value="'+ data[i].id + '" /><label for="'+ data[i].id +'">' + data[i].name + '</label><br/>');
}
```

then use code below to get text associated with each checked `checkbox`

```
$("input[name=catChkBox]:checked + label").text();
```

*update :*

to save values into the array use the code below :

```
function ConvertSelectedValuesToList()
{
  list = $("input[name=catChkBox]:checked + label").map(function () {
      return $(this).text();
  }).get();
}
```

if you want to create a comma separated string of values then add `join(",")` after `get()` .but then it's not an array anymore.

Comment: Wonderful. I want to store the options into a list as a  comma separated one. Any clues for it ?

Comment: @sahana : if you want a comma separated one then it's not a list , it's a string .

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input[name=catChkBox]:checked").val();
```

Comment: @llya it prints only the id and not the name (data[i].name)

Comment: because the "value" and "id" of the checkbox contain data[i].id in your example data[i].name is not a part of the checkbox

Comment: because the "value" and "id" of the checkbox contain data[i].id in your example data[i].name is not a part of the checkbox

Comment: @llya but i want only the options. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

`data[i].name` is never written to the input element and as such is not part of it. It is merely text following the element.

I would recommend to add a data-attribute **also** containing the value you are interested in, similar to this:

```
var list = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $('#cContainer').append('<input type="checkbox" data-name="' + data[i].name + '" name="catChkBox" class="ckbox" id = "' + data[i].id + '" value="' + data[i].id + '" /> ' + data[i].name + '<br/>');
}
```

Note `data-name="' + data[i].name + '"` above.

Then you can update your method to simply query the data attribute, similar to this:

```
function showSelectedValues() {
    alert("--------------" + $("input[name=catChkBox]:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).data('name');
    }).get().join(","));
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eHmjs/) - Using the data-attribute

---